# Importing Menu from another module to the main module in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, module, tkinter-menu

I have a menu bar in a module called views1.py and I am importing it into the main module using OOP.  Am getting no error message and no menu bar.  The window opens up as normal with other content loaded.  The application is being developed as a package and the directory structure is as follows :

The Main directory has two files main.py and README.rst and a directory called *lowercase* main. This directory *lowercase* main contains the views1.py, controller.py and model.py.

```
1. Main directory
    - main.py
    - README.rst
    - main directory
        * views1.py
        * model.py
        * controller.py
```

### main.py

```
    from tkinter import Tk
    import tkinter as tk
    import controller
    import views1
    from tkinter import *
    from views1 import Views1, Views2



    class AIcvmaker(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.Views2 = views1.Views2(tk)


            self.title("Cleopatra CV Maker")
            self.geometry("1400x800")
    
            #Add a view
            Views2(self)
            Views1(self).grid(sticky = (tk.E))
            self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    

    root = AIcvmaker()
    root.mainloop()
```

### views1.py

```
    from tkinter import Tk
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import messagebox
    import controller

    #code edited for Views1()
    class Views1(tk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

            self.controller = controller
            self.parent = parent
            self.cv_maker_Base()

        def cv_maker_Base(self):
            self.create_Rightframe()



        def create_Rightframe(self):
    
            self.pad_label = ttk.Label(self, text = "Push a button")
            self.activate_Button = ttk.Button(self, text = "Activate software")
            self.pad_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx = 8, pady = 8)
            self.activate_Button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx = 8, pady = 8)
            self.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)        

    #ADDING AN EXTRA self to super()
    class Views2(tk.Menu):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            super().__init__(self, parent)
            self.parent = parent
            self.create_Topmenu()

        def create_Topmenu(self):
            self.menu_bar = Menu(self.parent)
            self.create_Filemenu()
            self.create_Editmenu()
            self.create_Viewmenu()
            self.create_Aboutmenu()



        def create_Filemenu(self):

            self.filemenu = Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff = 0)
            self.filemenu.add_command(label="New", command = lambda: fNew())
            self.filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command= lambda: fOpen())
            self.filemenu.add_separator()
            self.filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command= lambda: fSave())
            self.filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
            self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)

        def create_Editmenu(self):
            pass

        def create_Viewmenu(self):
            pass
        def create_Aboutmenu(self):
            pass

        def fNew(self):
            pass
        def fOpen(self):
            pass
        def fSave(self):
            pass
```

I have tried to writing tk.Menu in the init method of Views2() and tried to change self to parent, it doesn't seem to work.  I working to write a MVC as the code is extremely long and this would help reduce the complexity.

Comment: Could you provide us a Minimal Working Code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? Besides the fact that we do not have `controller.py`, you are using `Views1`, which is not defined on your `views1.py`.

Comment: By the way, you do not need `import views1` if afterwards you are using `from views1 import Views1, Views2`. You are importing twice...

Comment: I understand I should not have put the full code, the controller.py has no consequence to the output and I can update Views1()

Comment: Further I have tried to put the line Views2(self) in main.py over Views1(self) and it doesn't show any output then.  Could it be a parent - child problem ?

Comment: @David Duran Thanks

Comment: Adding an extra line of code to the Class Views2(self), that made it work for me.

Comment: Yes, adding the line I provided in the calss `Views2` should also work.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to display the menu by using:

```
self.parent.config(menu=self.filemenu)
```

Under the function `create_Filemenu`:

```
def create_Filemenu(self):
    self.filemenu = Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff = 0)
    self.filemenu.add_command(label="New", command = lambda: self.fNew())
    self.filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command= lambda: self.fOpen())
    self.filemenu.add_separator()
    self.filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command= lambda: self.fSave())
    self.filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
    self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)
    
    # display the menu
    self.parent.config(menu=self.filemenu)
```

Note that I have changed some lines of code that were incorrect to make it work, such as commenting `self.Views2 = views1.Views2(tk)`, to which you should pass `self` and not `tk`. Or importing `ttk` in the views1.py file. Also changing from `fNew()` to `self.fNew()` for instance.

Output:

[image]